# Zero should be accepted in the input type number but not Negative values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, html

I am doing some validations for the input type.

```
<input 
    type="number" 
    min="0" 
    decimal-places="" 
    ng-model="candidate.ctc" 
    class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid-min ng-invalid ng-invalid-required candidateCTCInputPosition" 
    id="ctc" 
    placeholder="CCTC" 
    autocomplete="off" 
    required="">
```

Here, with this user is not able to take the `0` as an input, So, when user types the `0` then it is treating it as a `false` value.

So, user should not be able to type negative values using the `keyups` and also it should accept the `0`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: _"-ve"_? Please type out what you're trying to say instead of using nonexistent abbreviations. _"Minusve"_ is not a word.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Also update the title.

Comment: What about using `$valid`?

Comment: No I can not use $valid there as There is a bit problem with my controller scopes.

Comment: So I can suggest you to use ngDisabled on your submit button (if there's one) according to your validation wish

Comment: There is no submit button.

Comment: Try `onkeypress`.. something like this: `onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"`

Comment: Could you please port it in a answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/qoL16sup/

**Directive:**

```
decimalPlaces.$inject = ['$filter','$locale'];
function decimalPlaces($filter,$locale){
    return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope,element,attrs,ngModelCtrl){
        var groupSep = $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.GROUP_SEP;
        var decimalSep = $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.DECIMAL_SEP;
        var decimalPlaces = scope.$eval(attrs['decimalPlaces']) || 0;
        var pattern = decimalPlaces > 0 ? 
            new RegExp('^\\d*(\\'+ decimalSep +')?[0-9]{0,' + decimalPlaces + '}$') : new RegExp('^\\d*$');

        element.bind('keypress',function(e){
          var lastChar = e.charCode!==0?String.fromCharCode(e.charCode):'';
          var selectionStart = element[0].selectionStart;
          var selectionEnd = element[0].selectionEnd;
          var newVal = element.val().slice(0,selectionStart) + lastChar + element.val().slice(selectionEnd);

          if(!pattern.test(newVal)){
            e.preventDefault();
          }        
        });

      element.bind('blur',function(){
        var value = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue || ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
        if (ngModelCtrl.$isEmpty(value)) return null;
        if(pattern.test(value)){
          element.val($filter('number')(value,decimalPlaces));
        }else{
          element.val('');
          ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue('');
          ngModelCtrl.$commitViewValue();
        }
      });           

      element.bind('focus',function(){
        var value = ngModelCtrl.$modelValue || ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;
        if (ngModelCtrl.$isEmpty(value)) return null;      
        element.val(value);
      });

      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function(value){ 
        if (ngModelCtrl.$isEmpty(value)) return null;
        if(pattern.test(value)){
          value = parseFloat(value);
          if(decimalPlaces){
            value = value.toFixed(decimalPlaces);
          }else{
            value = Math.floor(value);
          }
          return parseFloat(value);
        }else{
          return null;
        }
      });

      if (angular.isDefined(attrs.min)) {
        var minVal = scope.$eval(attrs.min);
        ngModelCtrl.$validators.min = function(value) {
          return ngModelCtrl.$isEmpty(value) || angular.isUndefined(minVal) || value >= minVal;
        };
      }

      if (angular.isDefined(attrs.max)) {
        var maxVal = scope.$eval(attrs.max);
        ngModelCtrl.$validators.max = function(value) {
          return ngModelCtrl.$isEmpty(value) || angular.isUndefined(maxVal) || value <= maxVal;
        };
      }

    }
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate autocomplete="off">
<label>
  Decimal places = 0
  <input 
    type="text"
    name="input1"
    decimal-places="0" 
    ng-model="model.input1" 
    autocomplete="off" 
    required>
</label>
<br/> <br/>
<lable>
Decimal places = 2:
  <input 
    type="text"
    name="input2"
    decimal-places="2" 
    ng-model="model.input2" 
    autocomplete="off" 
    required>
</lable>

<br/> <br/>
<lable>
Decimal places = 2, min = 100, max = 10000:
  <input 
    type="text"
    name="input3"
    decimal-places="2" 
    min="100"
    max="10000"
    ng-model="model.input3" 
    autocomplete="off" 
    required>
</lable>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngPattern to validate the input. But it won't prevent the user from typing a negative number. Use a following function to avoid typing a negative value.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ctc").keydown(function(e){
  
        if (e.key == "." || e.key=="-") {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Preventing negative values</p>
<input type="number" min="0" max="10" decimal-places="" ng-model="candidate.ctc" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid-min ng-invalid ng-invalid-required candidateCTCInputPosition" id="ctc" placeholder="CCTC" autocomplete="off" style='width:300px' required=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this,

```
    var number = document.getElementById('ctc');
    number.onkeydown = function(e) {
        if(!((e.keyCode > 95 && e.keyCode < 106)
          || (e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 58) 
          || e.keyCode == 8)) {
            return false;

          }
    }
```